# Paging in Azure DevOps REST API

Tags: powershell, rest, azure-devops

I am currently trying to get the commit count of a specific branch with the Azure DevOps REST API by using PowerShell. Since the response is limited to 100 commits i have to use paging.
How can i do this?

The documentation just says

> link: ;rel="next"

which i do not understand.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get-commits?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP#paging

Comment: Not sure about this API in Azure DevOps, but in general, this works: https://jessehouwing.net/azure-devops-accessing-apis-with-large-volumes-of-data/

Comment: Looks like this API doesn't return the correct headers and that `rel=next` header it returns is useless.

Comment: I tested it with $top but i don't get a x-ms-continuation-token header

Comment: Yeah, you can probably page through it the poor mans way with `&searchCriteria.$top=50` & `&searchCriteria.$skip=X` until you get an empty set. But no way to be sure a new item was added at the top.

Comment: I found another way. I use the commit of the last value to restart the request until i don't get a value count of 100.